# Navigation menu not updating with current page link name after clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function myFunction () {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
    }


let current_url = document.location;
document.querySelectorAll(".topnav .btn").forEach(function(e){
    if(e.href == current_url){
        e.classList +=" current";
    }
});
```

```css
body, html {
margin-left:5%;
margin-right:5%;
margin-bottom:1%;
margin-top:1%;
}

.logopos {
    text-align:center;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius:5px;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family:"Lucida Console", monospace;
}




/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.btn {
    color:white;
}

.btn.current {
  background-color:#f58a42;
  color: white;
}


/* Change the color of links on hover */

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}


/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

 /* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

{% load static %}





<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a class ="btn"href="{% url 'project_index' %}">Apresentação</a>
  <a href="#news">Formação</a>
  <a class = "btn" href="{% url 'form_page' %}">Cadastro</a>
  <a href="#about">Contato</a>
  <a class = "icon" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>




<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="Profissional da área de psicopedagogia" content="Pagina Oficial">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>

{% block page_content %}{% endblock %}
```

Here's the issue..

Toggle menu shows up OK on mobile, but it only ever shows the firstlink that appears when you first access the page.
If i click other links, page loads ok but the menu sticks at "apresentacao" ...

I just copied this script from W3s and not sure if this behavior i desire to accomplish was intended, but it just feels odd that the page link isn't being updated. Feels like the client accessing the page will get an odd feeling from this.

https://jdihzy.pythonanywhere.com/ (the problem is only on mobile)

Answer (score 0):

in CSS change it to

```css
/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a {display: none;}
  .topnav a.current {display: block;} /* change to this so that only the current class is displayed */
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

I would rather have an empty span element in there, where you can fill in the current open page text using JS. but this works as well!